# How do i open already existing project in xcode downloaded from github?

Tags: ios, github, xcode8

I am very new to xcode.

I am trying to open an existing [Github project](https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen) as an example.

I downloaded it as a zip and tried to find xcodeproj file to open in Xcode (Ver 8.2) but couldn't find it.

Can you please let me know how can I do it? Also please let me know whether a new project should be opened in swift or objective c. (i opened in objective C mode but couldn't find a way to open the downloaded project)

Comment: Show screenshot of files under the folder you downloaded.

Comment: This folder does not contain the .xcodeproj file. It has only number of classes.

Comment: there are lot of files..but they are the same as the browsing of folders as is seen in https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen. You can browse the folders online there itself in the link.

Comment: @Amanpreet: Yes that's what I am wondering. It is published as a working code. So i don't understand how i can compile the same in my xcode editor. Any info in this regard will be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In this picture you can see the note by developers. They removed the .xcodeproj file. You have to drag and drop the required classes in your project.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should remove the default files and folders created by blank new project in xcode and add the files downloaded from project directly?

Comment: No need to remove. In your main project you can directly drag and drop the files from this downloaded folder.(i.e only if you clear which files are required for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the XCode project file is removed from this repo.

You can create your own new project and drag drop these files to your project. And set initial view controller in **App Delegate** or in **Storyboard**.

Comment: Can you give me a link or screen shots on how i can do the same? When i opened a blank new project..I am seeing various folders and files created already. So i am not understanding which ones to be removed and replaced with downloaded project files